# Install .deb package from shared folder on other PC with Windows

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, localrepository

I have PC with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and other PC with windows 10. I download repository with "ubuntu-repository.exe". On Windows I have directories with ubuntu repos. This directory:

```
.
└── rerository
    ├── dists
    │   └── focal
    │       └── main
    │           └── binary-amd64 -> Packages.gz
    ├── pool
        └── main
            ├── a
            └── b
             etc.
```

I try add in sources.list `deb file:/192.168.1.1/repository/ focal main`, but `sudo apt-get update` don't see my repos. How I can install my `.deb` files?

Comment: First, after the `file:` it should be `//`.  Also, I think instead of `file:` it should be either `http:` or `https:`.

Comment: I download repo to Ubuntu PC and `deb file:/home/user/soft/repository focal main` work,, but `sudo apt install ***` don't work steel.

Comment: Right, because that is local to the system.  You are trying to pull from another system that requires the `http://` instead of `file:/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setting up IIS FTP server on windows server 2012 r2 and share my repo with ftp, add "svchost.exe" in firewall exception(without it I can't connect to ftp-server).
On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS add setting through terminal `echo 'Dir::Bin::Metods::ftp "ftp"; ' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local-ftp`. It command add file local-ftp on apt settings(/etc/apt/apt.conf.d) else you can't update repo from ftp. And final add `deb [tusted=yes] ftp://ip.ip.ip.ip/ focal main universe multiverse restricted` in source.list file.
Then I edit file Release in repo root directory. I delete all except main/binary-amd64(and other like this). After all this sudo apt update work. And possible apt install synaptic(gluster and other) with all depence installing. Sory for my bad english.
It's work!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace `file:/` with `http` or `https`. If that isn't the solution, replace `file:/` with `file:///`.